# Best way to clean up code

Tags: angular, typescript

I have array

```
let awards = [
      {
        finished: 1,
        awardName: 'The beginning',
        description: 'Complete one excersise'
      },
      {
        finished: 5,
        awardName: 'Five of a kind',
        description: 'Complete five excersises'
      },
    ]
```

in my component, and it's cluttering my code. So what is the best practice, where should I put that. In my mind, I think it should go to separate file `awards.ts` and then import it to my component? I use that array like this

```
this.awards.forEach(award => {
    if (this.numbOfFinished === award.finished) {
      if (res.find(r => (r.key === award.awardName)))  ...
```

Is there dedicated type of file, like interface or something  in typescript / Angular for that kind of thing? Thanks.

Comment: You could create a Typescript class (e.g. `Award`), with the 3 properties in the constructor. See [this documentation page](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html).

Comment: What's exactly the purpose of those data? Is that it? May it be longer? Do you need to edit it later? Is that for mocking HTTP response?

Comment: @maxime1992 It can be longer. It's just the array of awards I set up, and it won't be dynamic, so it will not change. I will sure add more awards later on. Nope it's not mocking, it's just the list of awards, whom I loop through so when the criteria hit ( in this case 1 or 5 finished things) it will show congratulation message with those names and description. It's just the collection of awards.

Comment: If it's plain data, I'd put it in a json file FWIW.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd usually put those generated object in a separate service.

Create an AwardService and implement a getter, (if needed) a setter and a constructor.

Build up your object in the constructor (for instance).

Import the service where you need it in order to get an instance of the awards-object.

That's clean and recyclable.

Example

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class AwardService {

    private awards: any;

    constructor() {
        this.awards = [
              {
                finished: 1,
                awardName: 'The beginning',
                description: 'Complete one excersise'
              },
              {
                finished: 5,
                awardName: 'Five of a kind',
                description: 'Complete five excersises'
              },
        ]
    }

    public getAwards(): any {
        return this.awards;
    }

    // if needed
    public setAwards(value: any) {
        this.awards = value;
    }
}
```

Comment: And then I call it in my component like this `this.awards = this.awardService.getAwards()` ?

Comment: Correct. That's the way.